# jQuery Mobile + Cordova - on "tap" alert called twice

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

**jQM 1.3, Cordova, iOS**

Every time I trigger a tap event and the function called by the event contains an `alert`, it will be called twice.

Here, this will call an `alert`, and as soon as I press "OK" and try to tap/scroll anywhere else on the app a second `alert` will be displayed:

```
$(document).on('tap', '#mydiv', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('Tapped.');
   return false;
});
```

if I do this, `#result` will only contain "Tapped", how it is supposed to be.

```
$(document).on('tap', '#mydiv', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#result').append('Tapped');
   return false;
});
```

I don't really need `alerts`. Just for debugging.
However I am curious why this behavior occurs.
Why is that? **How can it be fixed?**

Thank you.

Comment: Console.log acts the same way? Do you bind those events to any page event?

Comment: Havn't tried console, because I need to add the plugin and I always forget to remove it afterwards. No, even if I place just the tap event without anything else in the `<head>` it gets triggered twice.

Comment: Try `touchstart` event.

Comment: @Omar `touchstart` works. Alert fires only once. But I noticed after closing the alert scrolling is "trapped" and the page needs always 2 pushes to scroll again (the first scroll is being "ignored").

Comment: Remove `preventDefault()` and `rerun false`. you can use `vclick`, `click` and `touchend` as well.

Comment: Ouh yes. without `preventDefault()` and `return false` it works. But `click` is too slow for mobile.  Do you have any explanation why the alert (and only the alert - every other action, like append, not) appears twice with `tap` but once with `touchstart`?

Comment: It could be a browser issue, have you tried it on different devices/platforms?

Answer (score 3):

Your code had issue problem. It will execute many time if you click many time on button. Why? Because once you click on button, event click will execute 1, and next click it will execute 1 + 1 event click of previous, and so on 1 + 1 + 1 if you click many time, ... 
Solution to prevent event fire many time:
 1. Use off() or one:

```
$(document).off().on('tap', '#mydiv', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('Tapped.');
   return false;
});

$(document).one('tap', '#mydiv', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('Tapped.');
   return false;
});
```

2.Use Flag

```
var flag = true
if( flag ){
    flag = false;
    $(document).on('tap', '#mydiv', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       alert('Tapped.');
       return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: I only tap **once** on the div. But the alert shows up twice. Anyway, your code `$(document).one` prevents the alert to be shown 2 times, **but** I don't want to limit it to a one time interaction. `off.on` does not work I tried that before.

Comment: Issue is you not remove old events and add new event to element. You should read document, tutorial careful before work

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and workaround that worked for me was to wrap alert into setTimeout

```
setTimeout('alert("Tapped.")',250);
```

It could be the same issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4686) where they came to conclusion that it is a browser bug.

> Basically, if you trigger a modal alert or prompt from a touchend event, clicking the buttons of the alert/prompt trigger another touchstart event that is targeted at the same element that triggered the original touch events, even if it is visually no where near the alert/prompt. The curious thing is that no matching touchend is dispatched after your finger goes up … I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that the alert is modal and the browser is still in the midst of processing the original touchend event that triggered the touchend/tap/vclick and your callback.
>
> The troubling part is that the next time you touch the screen, the
>   browser apparently ends up flushing the touchend event from the
>   alert/prompt dismissal, and that event is again targeted at the same
>   element from the previous touch events even if your finger is no where
>   near the element. This flushed touchend event is why callbacks seem to
>   fire twice.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that:

1. this issue only happens on iOS, not in Android.
2. It also happens when you introduce a prompt or something like that.

After trying every possible way supposed to avoid propagation, I've concluded that the problem has nothing to do with it (propagation), and the only practical solution that really worked has been Yuriy's, and it worked for me even with a shorter delay (50).